# Cross-section uncertainty of $^{56} Fe$ and $^{1}H$

Tags: nuclear-physics, error-analysis, scattering-cross-section

I was reading [Laura Clouvel 's thesis on Uncertainty in fast neutronic flux](http://www.theses.fr/s165847). In this document, Hydrogen and Iron seem to be the main source of uncertainty in a PWR reactor.
[image]
[image]
[image]
Intuitively, I would have thought the heavy nuclei would be the main sources of uncertainty but it seems not. On the contrary, I thought hydrogen was well-known but it seems not.
What are the reasons for these nuclei having such high uncertainties?

Comment: Iron in steel is the major component of the structure, hydrogen is the major component in water. Any uncertainty in cross sections of these elements heavily outweigh uncertainties in other minor elements in the system.

Comment: @JonCuster Possibly but wouldn't Carbon have a big part too since it's steel (Carbon + Iron alloy)?

Comment: There is not very much carbon in steel (say 0.05 to 0.25% in mild steel). Even high carbon steels only go up to a bit over 2%.

Answer (score 2):

As Jon Custer said, I misread the data. Here we are talking about the data integrated over the whole PWR and not specifically to each nuclei. The moderator is water which explains hydrogen and oxygen. The structure is steel, which is mostly iron.

Answer (score 0):

The thesis deals with the uncertainty on the fast flux received by the vessel hot spot and not over the whole PWR. We speak about "uncertainty" here. It means that you have to consider many "uncertain" input variables which have varying degrees of physical influence on the fast flux received by the vessel. 
Moreover, the fast flux means that the studied energy is over 1 MeV. According to the nuclear libraries in this energy field, we don't know very well the hydrogen cross-sections. And as said in the thesis, in water reactors, "hydrogen is a good neutron moderator because of its mass, which is almost identical to that of a neutron. During a collision with hydrogen, the neutron thus loses a part of its kinetic energy and hence slows down."